# If mouse up then call the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that calls a function. However, I would like the function to be called only on the event of a `Mouse Up`.

```
positionMenu : function(){
        if (positionMenuInvalidated) return;
        positionMenuInvalidated = true;
        setTimeout(_positionMenuNow,1); }
```

The `_positionMenuNow` which is called in `setTimeout` should happen only in the event of a mouse up. How can this condition be satisfied ?

Comment: on a mouseUp over what element?

Comment: You have to add more code or explain your situation better. Where are events being captured? why do you setTimeout that function if it is meant to be called only on mouse up?

Comment: I have a control that is being dragged and dropped on to a different location. Only when dropped, should the positionMenuNow function be called. Does that help to clarify ?

Comment: What API are you using for Drag & Drop? Native? jQuery UI? Usually events should be fired when you drop something.

Comment: That is JQueryUI..Please suggest..thanks

Comment: jQuery UI will fire a `stop` event that you can listen for when dragging stops: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()` to bind events to handler functions:

```
$('body' /* or any other selector */).on('mouseup', _positionMenu);
   ^                                      ^           ^
selection that the handler is bound to | event type | handler function (can also be an anonymous function)
```

Read about [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I apologize for the similar answer, but I am trying to express different idea other than the execution only.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the on mouseup code is getting executed anyhow to call the function _positionMenu. I think an if statement could do the trick. Could you specify something on those terms ? thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good idea to check whether the mouse is up or not while executing the timeout. Instead its better if you trigger the timeout after the `mouseup` has been triggered.

```
$('body').on('mouseup', function() {
   setTimeOut("_positionMenu()", 1000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply..
The timeout should execute or call the function after a delay of 1 sec only when the mouse is up or has been released..Does that help ?